# bottom up register allocation, reserving register for loads/stores

Tags: compiler-construction, bottom-up

Long time listener, first time caller :).

I am working on a local (per basic block) register allocator.
The method I am using is 'bottom-up' allocation.

I have been trying to find out if there is a better way to deal with loads/stores to memory (based on spills) than saving an int register for this task. I seem to remember someone telling me that saving a register for loads/stores was a lazy or unintelligent method. But for the life of me I cannot find a better strategy on the inter-webs.

I forgot to handle this and my compiler had an infinite regression of spills when I ran out of int registers.

Thank you all in advance!

-Tom